# JWT token custom lifetime validation and lifetime update

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

ASP.NET Core 6 app.
I have JWT authentication:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateActor = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,            
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            // ...
        };
    })
;
```

I want to do the next. I want to make tokens alive for 2 hours if user doesn't make any requests. If user sends a request, token's lifetime should be DateTime.UtcNow + 2hours. I think, I should store tokens in DB with their expire time and every request I have to to check this time from db and update it if it isn't expired.

I've investigated how to do that. I found:

**One**. TokenValidationParameters has LifetimeValidator property, which is a delegate. The problem is I can't use there any application services (e.g. DbContext). Also I thinks it isn't a correct place where I should update anithing (token time in my case)

**Two**. I can declare my class which implements ISecurityTokenValidator and use it like this:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
        options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new MyJwtSecurityTokenHandler());
        ...
    })
```

There is ValidateLifetime method, but again I can't use any services there. I don't know how to inject there anything.

How can I do custom token lifetime validation and lifetime update?

Answer (score 0):

See below pseudo code where stored the token to the handler and return the token as a string.

- expiryMin is a variable that holds the minutes in number. in your case, the value should be 120.

  ```
       double expiryMin = 120D;
       var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:Key"])); //Jwt:Key - reading from config 
       var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

       var token = new JwtSecurityToken(configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], 
                       null, expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expiryMin),
                       signingCredentials: credentials);                     // Jwt:Issuer - reading from config 

       return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
  ```

Comment: In this case I'll have a token which will be alive some specific period of time. After that specific period it will be invalid. I want every time a request with this token is made, the token expire date will prolongate.